# Microsoft Pinyin not compatible with Flex 4.5 and Flash Player 11

Tags: apache-flex, flash

My flex app is running in Flash Player 11, and when my client use Microsft Pinyin to input Chinese, the text property of textinput and textarea will get wrong chars that miss some characters, and the validators does not work, is there some way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting [IME mode on the TextInput](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#imeMode)?